# Delete multiple datas sharing a same child from Firebase - Java

Tags: java, android

I have the following Firebase database

lessons :

```
      Id_lesson : "XXX1"
      Name_lesson : "Geography"
      Date_lesson : "25/09/2018"

      Id_lesson : "XXX2"
      Name_lesson : "Mathematics"
      Date_lesson : "25/09/2018"

      Id_lesson : "XXX1"
      Name_lesson : "Physics"
      Date_lesson : "26/09/2018"

      Id_lesson : "XXX2"
      Name_lesson : "Biology"
      Date_lesson : "26/09/2018"
```

I need to delete all the lessons entries from a specific date (sharing the same Date_lesson child).

I tried this method :

```
private void Delete_CR_Lessons(Date date) {

    final String date_to_delete_string = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(date);
    Log.i("Tag", "date to delete : "+date_to_delete_string);

    DatabaseReference drTest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    drTest.child("lessons").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("Tag", "iteration for dataSnap");
                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(date_to_delete_string)){
                    dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w("TAG: ", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

During execution of the method (with String date "25/09/2018" for example), the entries are not deleted from Firebase Database. I see the two logs I specified  but I also see a log called

"I/chatty: uid=10298(com.example.myname.lessonsmanagment) identical 2 lines"

I suppose that the method doesn't work because it cannot detect both Lessons from date 25/09/2018 (Geography and Mathematics) on the same time.

Does anyone have an idea on how to make it work ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you need to query/order the data with the date

you can simply do it using this sample.

```
mRef.child("lessons").orderByKey().equalTo(Date_lesson)
.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

  for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
    String key = postsnapshot.getKey();
    dataSnapshot.getRef().removeValue(); 
 }
});
```

where `mRef`is you `lessons` branch ref

Comment: Thanks for your response. It still don't work, I'm still missing something. I will update my original post.